# How can I delete picklist values via the metadata API?

Tags: rest-api, picklist, metadata-api, metadata

I cannot find a way to delete picklist values via the metadata API. I have read a lot from the Salesforce Metadata API docs, but it doesn't say wither or not you can do this.

I'm using version 39.0 of the API, which did add quite a bit of functionality to the metadata API, but nowhere does it mention how to update/replace/delete existing picklist values, rather focusing on creating metedata instead. Fields etc. I can delete, but picklist values seems to have an information black hole.

Does anyone know if this is possible? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?  If so, please suggest.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deleting specific picklist value by using MetadataAPI](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/159873/deleting-specific-picklist-value-by-using-metadataapi)

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible.

You can update the picklist value set, which can deactivate picklist values, but you cannot delete them with the metadata api.

See a more detailed answer here:
[Deleting specific picklist value by using MetadataAPI](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/159873/deleting-specific-picklist-value-by-using-metadataapi/159973#159973)